# how to add video in this link

Tags: javascript, html, css

help me to add mp4 video to this code

```
<div class="cover-v1 jarallax" video src="video/cover_bg_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="home-section"></video>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
              
            <div class="col-md-7 mx-auto text-center">
              <h1 class="heading gsap-reveal-hero">CODEx Creators</h1>
              <h2 class="subheading gsap-reveal-hero"> Grandmaster of Artificial Intelligence</h2>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

i want to solve this problem

Comment: Add the closing bracket for the first `div` tag, and the starting bracket for `video` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use video tag like this:

```html
<div class="cover-v1 jarallax" id="home-section">
  <video width="300" height="200" controls>
    <source src="video/cover_bg_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-7 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="heading gsap-reveal-hero">CODEx Creators</h1>
      <h2 class="subheading gsap-reveal-hero"> Grandmaster of Artificial Intelligence</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```